# Drag an object from one viewController to other viewController

Tags: ipad, drag-and-drop

I am just creating a sample split view based iPad app where i am just displaying a list of sample object (e.g triangle,circle )in the left side view and right now i am trying to drag them to right hand side detail view.

So if i have 2 view controller (VC-A,VC-B) then how can i drag an object from View controller A to view controller B.